# MySQL index design with table partitioning

Tags: mysql, database-design, indexing, partitioning

I have 2 MySQL tables with the following schemas for a web site that's kinda like a magazine.

```
Article (articleId int auto increment ,
         title varchar(100),
         titleHash guid -- a hash of the title
         articleText varchar(4000)
         userId int)

User (userId int autoincrement
      userName varchar(30)
      email etc...)
```

The most important query is;

```
select title,articleText,userName,email 
from Article inner join user
on article.userId = user.UserId
where titleHash = <some hash>
```

I am thinking of using the articleId and titleHash columns together as a clustered primary y  for the Article table. And userId and userName as a primary key for the user table.
As the searches will be based on titlehash and userName columns.

Also titlehash and userName are unqiue by design and will not change normally.

The articleId and userid columns are not business keys and are not visible to the application, so they'll only be used for joins.

I'm going to use mysql table partitioning on the titlehash column so the selects will be faster as the db will be able to use partition elimination based on that column.

I'm using innoDB as the storage engine;

**So here are my questions;**

1. Do I need to create another index on
   the titlehash column  as the primary
   key (articleId,titlehash) is not
   good for the searches on the
   titlehash column as it is the second
   column on the primary key ?
2. What are the problems with this
   design ?

I need the selects to be very fast and expects the tables to have millions of rows and please note that the **int Id columns are not visible to the business layer** and can never be used to find a record

I'm from a sql server background and going to use mysql as using the partitioning on sql server will cost me a fortune as it is only available in the Enterprise edition.

So DB gurus, please help me; Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>As written, your "most important query" doesn't actually appear to involve the `User` table at all. If there isn't just something missing, the best way to speed this up will be to get the `User` table out of the picture and create an index on `titleHash`. Boom, done.</s>

<s>If there's another condition on that query, we'll need to know what it is to give any more specific advice.</s>

Given your changes, all that should be necessary as far as keys should be:

- On `Article`:

  - `PRIMARY KEY (articleId)` (no additional columns, don't try to be fancy)
  - `KEY (userId)`
  - `UNIQUE KEY (titleHash)`
- On `User`:

  - `PRIMARY KEY (userId)`

Don't try to get fancy with composite primary keys. Primary keys which just consist of an autoincrementing integer are handled more efficiently by InnoDB, as the key can be used internally as a row ID. In effect, you get one integer primary key "for free".

Above all else, test with real data and look at the results from `EXPLAIN`ing your query.

Comment: oops -- really sorry I missed it; userName and email are needed to be included in the query. Corrected now -- thanks for the quick reply

Comment: thanks - but what about the table partitioning wouldn't it give a performance improvement if done on the titlehash column ?. And the other thing is the partitioning column must be a part of the primary key. So if we need to use the partitioning we must put titlehash in the PK. Also as the auto inc int column is already the fisrt col in the clutered PK, will it be a problem for mysql to sort it  ?

Comment: Partition elimination (the optimization you're gunning for here) is only really useful for range queries (e.g, `col BETWEEN 123 AND 456`. Since range queries are useless on a hash, having a "normal" index on that column is just as efficient.

Comment: Ok but suppose : I have the table partitioned to 1000 partitions based on the titlehash which is unique. So it'll distribute the rows evenly throughout the partitions. i.e. if the table had 100 million rows, a partition will only have 100,000 rows. So that when doing a select on the titlehash column mysql only needs to seek the part of the uniquekey(titlehash) which is in the same partition as the data row (it's also partitioned), so the index seek will be a lot faster.   also Inserts won't suffer as the PK(articlId,titlehash) has the indentity col which is already sorted; Am I correct here ?

Comment: The performance impact you'd get from having to store the extra metadata for 1000 different tables is likely to be more significant than the speedup you'd get by having them.

Comment: Are partitions treated as different tables ? I come from a SQL Server background and it handles a 1000 partitions without any issue (I've got practical experience). Is my sql not capable of handling that number of partitions ? actually my main reason to move to mysql was the partitioning support as in MS SQL u need to pay about $25k to use it(for enterprise edition) :(

Comment: Yes. MySQL partitioning quite literally just splits the table up into a bunch of sub-tables, with all the performance gotchas that implies. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html for details.

Comment: Yes you are correct I ran extensive tests with 1000 simultaneous connections and 1 million rows but the performance gain from the partitioning (if there's any at all) is negligible. Also when there are too many partitions (about 1000) my pc  (core2duo 2 GB) cannot even handle inserts :(